# I ran into an error while trying to run npm install in my laravel project

Tags: laravel, node-modules, npm-install

I tried to run `npm install` in my `laravel project` but got the following `error`.
I have also tried to upgrade `npm` and got the same error. I tried some of the solutions I found online but non of them helped to resolve the problem.

```
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\chownr\chownr.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Comment: I managed to fix it by deleting `npm` folder and `npm-cache` folder.

Comment: the folders are in `.../Appdata/Roaming/`